# Undefined local variable or method `e' inside subscriptions controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, undefined, stripe-payments, rescue

I am getting the following error on my Rails 4.2 application. I'm trying to setup subscriptions with Stripe. A subscription belongs to a business and has_one plan. The error I am getting is below and my code follows. Forgive me if this is a beginner question.

[image: NameError]

**Subscriptions Controller**

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_subscription, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /subscriptions
  def index
    @subscriptions = Subscription.all
  end

  # GET /subscriptions/1
  def show
  end

  # GET /subscriptions/new
  def new
    @subscription = Subscription.new
    @plan = Plan.find_by id: params["plan_id"]
    @business = Business.find_by id: params["business_id"]
  end

  # POST /subscriptions
  def create
    @subscription = Subscription.new subscription_params.merge(email: stripe_params["stripeEmail"],
                                                               card_token: stripe_params["stripeToken"])
    raise "Please, check subscription errors" unless @subscription.valid?
    @subscription.process_payment
    @subscription.save
    redirect_to @subscription, notice: 'Subscription was successfully created.'
  rescue
    flash[:error] = e.message
    render :new
  end

  private
    def stripe_params
      params.permit :stripeEmail, :stripeToken
    end
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_subscription
      @subscription = Subscription.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def subscription_params
      params.require(:subscription).permit(:plan_id, :business_id)
    end
end
```

**Subscription Model**

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :business
  has_one :plan

  def process_payment
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create email: email,
                                       card: card_token

    Stripe::Charge.create customer: customer.id,
                          amount: plan.price * 100,
                          description: plan.name,
                          currency: 'usd'

  end

end
```

**Subscription View (new.html.erb)**

```
<%= form_for @subscription do |f| %>
  <% if @subscription.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@subscription.errors.count, "error") %>
        prohibited this subscription from being saved:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @subscription.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li>
            <%= message %>
          </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <h1><%= @business.name %></h1>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.hidden_field :plan_id, value: @plan.id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.hidden_field :business_id, value: @business.id %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <script
      src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
      data-key="<%= Rails.application.secrets.stripe_publishable_key %>"
      data-image="/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
      data-name="Business Name"
      data-description="<%= @plan.name %>"
      data-amount="<%= @plan.price*100 %>">
    </script>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Plan Model**

```
class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :subscription

end
```

**EDIT**

```
...
rescue Exception => e
  flash[:error] = e.message
  render :new
...
```

I made the above change and now I have seeing this error?

[image]

Comment: Where have you defined `e`?

Comment: You are missing `Exception => e`

Comment: @Pavan any idea on why I am getting the new issue?

Comment: @steveklein would you happen to know why I am getting the new error?

Comment: I've never seen that syntax for `find_by` and cannot get it to work properly in my Rails console.  If you are passing in `plan_id` in your `params` from your route, why not simply use `@plan = Plan.find(params["plan_id"])`?

Comment: @steveklein still the same error... When I go to the "new" page initially the business and plan id are present, when I submit my form I get the following error if that helps.

Comment: You should really post this as a new question.

Comment: @steveklein I posted a new question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31350606/subscription-form-with-stripe-not-passing-parameters-properly

Answer (score 0):

As it says `undefined method id for nil class`. Your `@plan` is nil, empty. Probably because you are not getting any parameters in this line `@plan = Plan.find_by id: params["plan_id"]`.

If you aren't passing the `plan_id` using something like a url query or a post from somewhere it will no work.

Your code says that `plan belongs_to subscription`, so either you choose a `plan` inside the new subscription form or you pass the parameter as i said above.

As we can see from the image, the params hash can be accessed by  `params[:subscription][:plan_id]`.

Comment: I thought I was passing the plan_id and business_id parameters, in the second image I included at the bottom it reads:

"subscription"=>{"plan_id"=>"2", "business_id"=>"1001"},

Comment: @JustinSeidl The `plan_id` is inside `subscription`. So you should access with `params[:subscription][:plan_id]`.